# sql select count from table by another table values

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

i am beginner to sql database 
i want some help .... i have two tables (families_table ) and (children_table ) that related via family_id so every family in families table has many of children in children table ...
i want to select some families from family table , and know the number of children for all selected families .. i tries to do this by

```
select count (*) from dbo.Children where family_id in (select top 50 percent * from dbo.Families where economic_state = 'a' or economic_state = 'j')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `count` for such a query:

```
select f.family_id, count(*)
from dbo.Families f
inner join dbo.Children c ON c.family_id = f.family_id
where f.economic_state = 'a' or f.economic_state = 'j'
group by f.family_id
```

EDIT:

If you need to return only top 50 percent, you can simply add it to the query above. As it does the join and count first, it will return 50 percent from the join result:

```
select top 50 percent f.family_id, count(*)
from dbo.Families f
inner join dbo.Children c ON c.family_id = f.family_id
where f.economic_state = 'a' or f.economic_state = 'j'
group by f.family_id
```

Comment: i don't want to select just family_id from families table .. i want to select 50 percent from families table.

Comment: You can wrap that query in another Select query to get the rest of the information.

Comment: i try your code and assign children count to textbox ..but every time the returned value to textbox is 1 ... why ??

Comment: hello Szymon again thank you for your code .. but there is another problem .. i use percentage to select families from families table .. your code is perfect bu when i use percentage the program also return children count by percentage ... so how can i select percentage from families and all children that related to families ... my query is :select count(*) Children c from (select top('" + int.Parse(percentCb2.Text) + "') percent f.family_id ,f.economic_state from dbo.families f on c.family_id = f.family_id where f.family_id = 1)fq group by fq.family_id

Comment: Modified my answer. Also, don't concatenate the query like that, you should use parameters to guard against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Modified from Szymon's answer to allow you to include other columns from the table.

```
select *
FROM
    (select f.family_id, count(*) children
    from dbo.Families f
    inner join dbo.Children c ON c.family_id = f.family_id
    where f.economic_state = 'a' or f.economic_state = 'j'
    group by f.family_id) fc
JOIN dbo.Families f ON f.family_id = fc.family_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

use join and group by:

```
SELECT children.fid, families.eco_state, count(children.fid) FROM children, families where children.fid= families.id and families.eco_state = 'a'
```

Group by children.fid

Answer (score 0):

You can use Common Table Expression(Cte) to write such query with readability.

```
;With CteFamily AS
(
SELECT family_id FROM dbo.Families 
--WHERE --Put your conditions to filter family
),
--get childrens count, with family id for selected family
CteChildrenCount AS
(
 SELECT family_id , Count(*) As ChildrenCount
 FROM  dbo.Children 
 WHERE family_id  IN (SELECT family_id FROM CteFamily)
 GROUP BY family_id 
),
--final query to get all other details from family table
CteFamilyDetails AS
(
  SELECT f.economic_state,f.family_id ,ChildrenCount   --Add extra columns from family       --table here
  FROM dbo.Families f
 INNER JOIN CteChildrenCount  c
 ON f.family_id = c.family_id
)
SELECT * FROM CteFamilyDetails;    --End of Cte end with semicolon.
```